# Should apache still be making error_log files?

Tags: logs, apache-httpd, php

I have a VirtualHost set up like this

```
<VirtualHost my.ip.address.here:80>
   DocumentRoot /home/todieama/public_html/dev/hop/public_html/
   ServerName dev.example.com
   ServerAlias dev.example.com
   ErrorLog /home/todieama/public_html/dev/hop/public_html/application/logs/apache.log
   ServerAdmin some@example.com
   UserDir enabled todieama
   <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
     suPHP_UserGroup todieama todieama
   </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

When a PHP error is caught, it gets logged in the apache.log file defined above, and also in error_log in dev/hop/public_html. Should it still be logging here? I'd like to stop if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could hash the `Errorlog` line from the configuration file *httpd.conf*.

Comment: In httpd.conf I just have one ErrorLog line, `ErrorLog "logs/error_log"`. Could this be causing it even though the file is in the root rather than a logs folder?

Comment: Also, if just changed it to `ErrorLog "logs/error_log.test.log"`, restarted apache, removed the old `error_log` file, and run a script what throws some fatal errors, and the `error_log` file was made again, not an `error_log.test.log` file